# How to fix "Missing Operand" in Batch Script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, variables, cmd

I've got a batch script that produces the exact final output that I'm looking for, but there are two "missing operand" messages prior to the final output.  I've combed through dozens of threads online trying to figure out how to resolve/prevent these message, but I haven't been able to find a fix yet...

Here's my script:

```sh
:Start
cls
@echo off

REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM [ Remotely Verify Max RAM Capacity & Required Stick Sizes & Quantities) ]
REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------

Set /P "Computer=Enter the Computer Name: "

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%G in ('wmic /node:"%Computer%" memphysical get MaxCapacity^, MemoryDevices') do (set /A "ramcapacity=%%G" & set /A "ramslots=%%H")
set /A "trueram=ramcapacity/1048576"
set /A "sticksizes=ramcapacity/1048576/ramslots"
echo Max RAM = %trueram%GB / %ramslots% sticks @ %sticksizes%GB

Goto End

:End
```

And here's an example of the output:

```
Missing operand.
Missing operand.
Max RAM = 64GB / 4 sticks @ 16GB
```

Since I'm able to get the output I'm expecting, the missing operand messages aren't a deal breaker, but I'd still like to figure out why they're occurring and how to prevent them (if possible).

Comment: Cure the symptom - redirect error output: `(FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%G in ('wmic /node:"%Computer%" memphysical get MaxCapacity^, MemoryDevices') do (set /A "ramcapacity=%%G" & set /A "ramslots=%%H")) 2> Nul`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `wcic` has that ugly line ending of `CRCRLF` instead of just `CRLF`. The first `CR` becomes part of the variable `%%G`/`%%H`. As the calculation is correct, you can just suppress the errormessage with `2>nul`. To really cure the problem, the safest and most generic way is to post-process the value with another `for` loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%G in ('wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity^, MemoryDevices') do (
  for /f %%a in ("%%G") do set "ramcapacity=%%a"
  for /f %%a in ("%%H") do set "ramslots=%%a"
)
set /A "trueram=ramcapacity/1048576"
set /A "sticksizes=ramcapacity/1048576/ramslots"
echo Max RAM = %trueram%GB / %ramslots% sticks @ %sticksizes%GB
```

Note: you don't really need `set /a` within the `for` loop. To simply assign a number to a variable, `set var=12345` is sufficient. Use `set /a` only to do arithmetic.

Another way is to avoid using a string at the end of a line. In the following code, I added (but then didn't use) a third token (`Width` - the last available one with `wmic memphysical`, as `wmic` sorts the columns alphabetically), so both `%%G` and `%%H` don't include `CR`. I also used `^|findstr /v "^$"` to skip empty lines (which would overwrite our variables with empty values):

```
@echo off
setlocal
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%G in ('wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity^, MemoryDevices^,Width ^|findstr /v "^$"') do (
  set "ramcapacity=%%G"
  set "ramslots=%%H"
)
set /A "trueram=ramcapacity/1048576"
set /A "sticksizes=ramcapacity/1048576/ramslots"
echo Max RAM = %trueram%GB / %ramslots% sticks @ %sticksizes%GB
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and insight Stephan!  It'll take me some time to get my head around the info that you and aschipfl posted, (I don't have even close to the amount of knowledge and experience you guys have) but I really appreciate being able to learn from experts like you guys!

Comment: We all started, where you did. We are just a few years ahead. At some point, you too will get some knots in your brain that make you "think batch". `:D`

Comment: Thank you so much for that - it means a lot coming from someone like you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```cmd
do (set /A "ramcapacity=%%G" & set /A "ramslots=%%H")
```

simply write:

```cmd
do (set /A "ramcapacity=%%G" & set /A "ramslots=%%H") 2> nul
```

The [`2> nul` portion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) simply suppresses the error messages.

---

The root cause of the error message is the fact that `wmic` returns Unicode text, which `for /F` fails to correctly convert it to ASCII/ANSI text, because it leaves behind orphaned carriage-return characters. So in your situation, after the line with the memory information, `for /F` iterates once more, making available such a character in `%%G`, hence trying to use it by `set /A "ramcapacity=%%G"`, which finally returns the error message.

To avoid such conversion artefacts, nest another `for /F` loop, like this:

```cmd
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%I in ('
    wmic /NODE:"%Computer%" MemPhysical get MaxCapacity^,MemoryDevices
') do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%G in ("%%I") do (
        set /A "ramcapacity=%%G" & set /A "ramslots=%%H"
    )
)
```

---

In general I recommend to use the `/VALUE` option of the `wmic` command, resulting in the following output:

> ```cmd
> MaxCapacity=67108864
> MemoryDevices=4
> ```

because this avoids value strings being padded to the right with spaces (though they do not disturb in your situation since you are using `set /A`):

```cmd
set "ramcapacity=" & rem // (ensure this variable is initially undefined)
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    wmic /NODE:"%Computer%" MemPhysical get MaxCapacity^,MemoryDevices /VALUE
') do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ("%%I") do (
        rem // The condition ensures that the only first line is processed:
        if not defined ramcapacity set /A "ramcapacity=%%J"
        rem // Here is no condition, so the last (second) line is relevant:
        set /A "ramslots=%%J"
    )
)
```

---

I would even go one step further and avoid explicit definition of variables like `ramcapacity` and `ramslots`, because returned strings `MaxCapacity=67108864` and `MemoryDevices=4` already look like perfect expressions for the `set` command:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    wmic /NODE:"%Computer%" MemPhysical get MaxCapacity^,MemoryDevices /VALUE
') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ("%%I") do (
        rem // This implicitly defines variables `MaxCapacity` and `MemoryDevices`:
        set /A "%%J"
    )
)
set /A "TrueRAM=MaxCapacity/(1<<20), StickSizes=TrueRAM/MemoryDevices"
echo Max RAM = %TrueRAM% GiB / %MemoryDevices% sticks @ %StickSizes% GiB
```

Comment: After reading what both you and Stephan said, I'm confused about your use of `set /A "%%J"` inside the for loop, since it's not being used to do a math calculation :-/... Thank you **so much** though for all the info and examples! I feel very blessed to be able to learn from code veterans like you guys!

Comment: I said "you don't *really* need...", meaning it works with or without `/a` (without is a tiny fraction of a second faster, so it's "recommended" this way. But you need a tight loop with many iterations to notice the difference)

Comment: Well, I consider the `/A` option as optional here. Speed is surely not a problem in this particular situation, because `wmic` is *much* slower than `set /A`. In general, if you have got a loop with many iterations, one should perhaps prefer not using `/A` due to performance. For a few assignments, I prefer using the `/A` option for code clarity reasons, because one can immediately see the value is intended to be an integer rather than a string. But anyway, it is nothing but a matter of taste at the end…

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the info! I've learned a lot from this one single thread.  It gets me excited to keep digging in and learning even more!